# Thought process behind the two sums solution (leetcode)? - Python 3

Tags: python, algorithm

```
    class Solution:
        def twoSum(self, nums, target):
            """
            :type nums: List[int]
            :type target: int
            :rtype: List[int]
            """
            h = {}
            for i, num in enumerate(nums):
                n = target - num
                if n not in h:
                    h[num] = i
                else:
                    return [h[n], i]
```

E.g. nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9 --> Answer: [0, 1]

---

Solution is posted above. I know there's plenty of sources of explanations of solutions so far. I understand what each line of the code does and how it is used to arrive at the answer. My dilemma is...how does one conceptualize the answer from scratch? Why does one think to themselves that n = target - num is essential?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, basically my thought process for solving the question may turn out like this
:

(Paraphrasing the question for readers understanding): Return indices of two integers in a given list whose sum is equal to a given target.

i. Like try brute force - which basically mean to add every unique pair of elements in the list, until we get a pair whose sum is equal to the target.

Time Complexity: O(N<sup>2</sup>) in Worst case. Ex: nums_list = [1,2,3,4] and target = 7

ii. Now, can we reduce the time complexity to O(N)? which means I need to iterate the list only using a single loop, in laymam's terms.

So, iterating only once means, we need to store some values about the visited elements which would help us to find the pair as we iterate the list.

Let us take this small example, given that our target = 10 and our element pair is [A,B], if A = 3, we are for sure that B = 10 - 3 = 7. So, we can check if we have an element B(Difference b/w target and A) in visited elements, if the current element is A, given the target.

So, this given us an idea list keep a track of all visited elements and if the difference between the Target value and the current element is already a visited element, then HOLA!!

We got the pair i.e [Current element, Target - Current element (if available in the visited elements list)]

Just renaming the given code to improve code readability!

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, list_nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        visited_elements = {}
        for index, num in enumerate(list_nums):
            difference = target - num
            if difference not in visited_elements:
                visited_elements[num] = index
            else:
                return [visited_elements[difference], index]
```

So, that my thought process behind "n = target - num" :)